# Remove a certain text from a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

For the following html.

```
<div id="textDiv">
<p>
MonkeyDonkey is not a bird. 
Monkey is an animal. 
</p>
</div>
```

I want to remove the text "**Donkey**".

I tried this but its not working.

```
$('#textDiv').html().replace("Donkey","");
```

Kindly let me know how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```js
var $text = $('#textDiv');
$text.html( $text.html().replace("Donkey", "") );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textDiv">
  <p>
    MonkeyDonkey is not a bird. 
    Monkey is an animal. 
  <p>
</div>
```

also you can use `RegExp` with `g` flag to replace all matches instead of just the first

```js
var $text = $('#textDiv');
$text.html( $text.html().replace(/Donkey/g, '') );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textDiv">
  <p>
    MonkeyDonkey is not a bird. 
    Monkey is an animalDonkey. Donkey 
  <p>
</div>
```